# Limiting while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Is there a way to limiting while loops when fetching data from mysql ?

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM  `table` 
    WHERE user_id = '$id' 
    ORDER BY `ID` DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //stuff
}
```

Here i dont want to use mysql's LIMIT function, can i limit while loop other than that one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always `break` the loop when it reaches its target. Otherwise you can use a `for` loop as Nick suggested.

```
$count = 0;

while ($count < 4 && $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //stuff

    $count++;
}
```

However note that it may be a better idea to limit the result-set from the query with the `LIMIT` command.

Comment: so how will i know if it fetched for example 4 records ?

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. However note that it may be a better idea to limit your loop from the SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop. For example, to loop through *up to* five rows...

```
for ($i = 0; $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i < 5; ++$i) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check for the number of rows:

```
while ($rowcount < 100 && $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rowcount += 1;
//stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to end a loop.

So, it could be

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=0;

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if($info=="what you're looking for"){ $count+=1; }

if($count >= 4){ break; }//break will exit the while loop
}
```

[break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) php docs

Answer (score 0):

You can always jump out of your PHP loop early - but you should be using the mysql LIMIT clause for this - the entire result set is fetched from the database and transfered to the client when you call mysql_query() potentially creating memory and performance problems.

Comment: i have some data that cant be filtered with mysql query and i need to check all fields thats why i am filtering them in while loop, so i needed to limit while loop