# How to check if value exists in DB with a loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I generate a random string but I need to check if it exists in DB and keep generating until it doesn't and then insert. This must be done somehow with a loop. But I can't think of how to do it.

```
public function checkEncryptId($encryptId) {
    $sql = "SELECT encrypt_id FROM table WHERE encrypt_id = :encryptId";
    $result = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":encryptId", $encryptId, PDO::PARAM_STR)
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!$data) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$length = rand(5, strlen($_GET['encrypt']));
$encryptId = $this->generateRandomString($length);
$uniqueEncryptId = $this->checkEncryptId($encryptId);
if ($uniqueEncryptId) {
   echo 'found';
};
if($this->insertData($encryptId, $encryptedMsg)) {
    echo json_encode($encryptId); 
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Just put what you have inside a `while (true)` loop. When the function says the ID doesn't exist, break out of the loop and insert the new row.

Comment: @Barmar, I can't because the generated string comes before it gets checked.

Comment: The generated string should be in the loop.

Comment: how do you then define if it's true? `while (true)` if it's in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code that generates and checks the string in a loop. Break out of the loop when the ID isn't found.

```
while (true) {
    $encryptId = $this->generateRandomString($length);
    if (!$this->checkEncryptId($encryptId)) {
        break;
    }
}
if($this->insertData($encryptId, $encryptedMsg)) {
    echo json_encode($encryptId); 
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I have a question. What if `generateRandomString` runs out of generated strings. How do I get out of the loop?

Comment: You can add a counter and break when the counter reaches a limit.

Comment: Is there some example I could look at?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075590/limiting-while-loop

Comment: But really, this is trivial programming that even a beginner should be able to figure out.

Comment: ok, I figured it out but not with a counter but variable assignment. Similar...If previous var equals to the new one.

Comment: Why would it be the same as the previous iteration? Isn't it random each time?

Comment: Crap, you're right. I guess the only way to do this then is to limit the number of iteration. Like try 10 times and then break out of loop otherwise it will keep checking until it times out.

Comment: If you make the random string long enough, the chance of duplicates should be vanishingly small. Usually it will find an unused string after just 1 or 2 tries.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping. I just need to have some checks in place to notify the user in case it happens. but I think this should be good enough for now. Thanks!